# Novice: Sqlite from php

Tags: php, sqlite

I am completely new to php and wish to read data from a sqlite database.

I have got the hello world to work correctly but the following two scripts failed to execute without an error:

```
<?php echo sqlite_libversion(); ?>         
<?php print_r(SQLite3::version()); ?>
```

The first script gives the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_libversion()
```

The server on which I have my website has the following php configuration.

http://php.binerorockar.se/

where it shows:

```
pdo_sqlite: PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
```

Do I have sqlite3 support? How can I test this support?

Comment: your phpinfo shows that you have pdo_sqlite support

Comment: @middaparka Yes thats the error I'm getting for the first script. If I dont have the driver then why do I have pdo_sqlite under php_info?

Comment: There's usually multiple extensions. (Specifically, you'll have `extension=pdo.so`, `extension=sqlite.so` and `extension=pdo_sqlite.so` lines in your config. Perhaps the "plain" SQLite extension isn't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to access a SQLite from PHP. In your examples, you are using the [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) and [SQLite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) extensions for PHP. But you have neither of these extensions actually installed in your PHP system.

You do have the [SQLite driver for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) installed. This is the generic API for SQLite and other databases. The syntax would look like this to get the SQLite software version.

```
// connect to in-memory SQLite database
$db = new PDO("sqlite::memory");
echo $db->query("SELECT sqlite_version()")->fetchColumn();
```

To use the SQLite specific API functions, need to uncomment `extension=sqlite.so` in the PHP config file.